# Apache options problem

Tags: apache-2.2

```
httpd -k start -DSSL
```

What does `-DSSL` mean here?

Answer (score 5):

this means, that apache will be started with SSL support. this defines the variable SSL and in your config shoud be a line like this somewhere:

```
<IfDefine SSL>
...
</IfDefine>
```

everything between the `IfDefine` lines will only be activated when `-DSSL` is set.

Answer (score 3):

The [man page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) of `httpd` says:

> **-D parameter**
>
> Sets a configuration parameter which can be used with `<IfDefine>` sections in the 
>   configuration files to conditionally skip or process commands at server startup and restart. 
>   Also can be used to set certain less-common startup parameters including `-DNO_DETACH`
>   (prevent the parent from forking) and `-DFOREGROUND` (prevent the parent from calling `setsid()` et al).

Answer (score 0):

It turns on SSL support.  I don't tend to do it this way, but use a2enmod to enable the SSL module, and SSLEngine On in the vhost config.

From the httpd manpage:

> httpd can be made to support HTTPS transactions if RSA certificates are generated and the utility is started with the -DSSL flag.  See ssl(8) for further information.